# Simple Calculation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple javascript calculation script, but for some reason can't get it work.

```js
  function calculate() {
    var USERINPUT1 = document.TESTING.INPUT1.value,
      RESULT = USERINPUT1 + (USERINPUT1 * .05);
    document.TESTING.OUTPUT1.value = RESULT;
  }
```

```html
<form name="TESTING">
  <table border="1" width="600" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        <h1>5% TAX CALCULATOR</h1>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3>ORIGINAL PRICE</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>ORIGINAL PRICE + 5% TAX</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="INPUT1" id="input" onchange="calculate();" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="OUTPUT1" id="output">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

When I enter `100` into `INPUT`, the `OUTPUT` becomes `1005`, but it should be `105`.

Could you please point out where the mistake is? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.TESTING.INPUT1.value` returns string. You need to convert into number so as to perform mathematical operations.

Hence, update from

```
var USERINPUT1 = document.TESTING.INPUT1.value,
```

to

```
 var USERINPUT1 = parseFloat(document.TESTING.INPUT1.value),
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/kRxK8Kf4fO6N8E9v9D2W?p=preview